# What are spring.status.value|expression|errorMessages?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm new to Freemarker and am trying to incorporate it with Spring. I see references to spring.status.expression and spring.status.value and spring.status.errorMessages, but no where have I found a description of what they are.

I'm not sure if they're specific to forms, but that is where I find the references. Example:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    Name:
    <@spring.bind "command.name" />
    <input type="text"
        name="${spring.status.expression}"
        value="${spring.status.value?default("")}" /><br>
    <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>
    <br>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

All help appreciated!

Thanks.

Les

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these are related to forms and field errors. It's exactly like the Spring binding in JSP (just better!): https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-tld.html#spring.tld.bind